# merging two pandas dataframe with one common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look something like this:

```
50       51           100            The Treasure of the Sierra Madre (1948)
51       52            98                                          Up (2009)
52       53           100             12 Angry Men (Twelve Angry Men) (1957)
53       54           100      The 400 Blows (Les Quatre cents coups) (1959)

                                    title viewers_score number_of_viewers_ratings
0  12 Angry Men (Twelve Angry Men) (1957)            97                    103672
1                     The 39 Steps (1935)            86                     23647
2     The Adventures of Robin Hood (1938)            89                     33584
3                    All About Eve (1950)            94                     44564
4   All Quiet on the Western Front (1930)            89                     17768
```

[dataframes head from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVPRS.png)

and I want to join them, I tried pandas 'merge':

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df,df_,on='title)
```

but it doesn't work because the title columns in the dataframes aren't in the same order, so when I tried it, I get a false in all rows and so an empty dataframe. how can I merge the two of them based on the common 'title' column?

Comment: You have no similar titles in both dataframes, so you get the empty result. For example, The Wizard of Oz is in the first dataframe, but not in the second one.

Comment: that's not the complete dataframe, it has 100 rows, I'm just showing the first 5 rows

Comment: Then post these that are overlapping.

Comment: I edited the first dataframe

Comment: Merged it succesfully, 12 Angry Men is in the third dataframe. There is a typo or extra space or something else in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Merging dataframes looks like this:

```
df_merge = df.merge(df_, on='title')
```

Comment: I think the syntax is fine, the problem is that the titles aren't in the same order in the two dataframes, so I got an empty dataframe.......PS. I tried yours and still doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcoNashaat The order of columns does not matter. Post your dataframes in your question as a text. Btw, what you've posted here has no equal titles, maybe it is the reason?

Comment: Could you give an example of data?

Comment: @Michael no, they are exactly the same titles. I'm just showing the first few rows

Comment: @kağanhazalkoçdemir image of the two dataframes is linked in the post.

Comment: @MarcoNashaat The reason for posting it as a text is to have ability to copy and paste it in Python interpreter. It is kind of a rule on this site.

Comment: ok sorry, edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
left_table.merge(right_table, on='title')
```

thats it. If you had an error, you didn't give much information to look at it.